# Coroutine does not run on button click in Pyside6

Tags: python, python-asyncio, pyside6

I am trying to run a coroutine which gets data on a button click. It uses `aiohttp` to get the data. The button is decorated with `@asyncSlot()` from `qasync` However, when I click the button, nothing happens, not even a print statement. I do not think the asyncio examples [examples](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/examples/example_async_minimal.html) match my use case. I have tried moving when asyncio runs around to see if that helps. I am a little stumped as I get no errors to work with. Why is my function not running?

My code:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.container = QWidget()  # Controls container widget.
        self.controlsLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        # -- Search bar and settings button
        self.search_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.search_bar = QLineEdit()
        self.search_button = QPushButton("Search")     
        self.search_button.clicked.connect(self.update_data)  # search by entered text
        self.search_layout.addWidget(self.search_button)
        self.controlsLayout.addLayout(self.search_layout)

        # Our tab container with adjustable number of tabs
        self.tab_container = TabContainer()
        # Add out tabs widget
        self.controlsLayout.addWidget(self.tab_container)
        self.container.setLayout(self.controlsLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.container

    @asyncSlot()
    async def update_data(self):
        stock_tickers = self.search_bar.text()

        print("Entered tickers: ", stock_tickers)

        short_interest = asyncio.create_task(self.setup_data(stock))
        short_interest = await short_interest
        print('SHORT INTEREST:', short_interest)

        # Make a table in a new tab here
        # ..............................


    async def setup_data(self, stock):
        short_interest = await get_data(stock)   # this function is our main coroutine
        # process the data here ...... as previous method return json


async def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    loop = qasync.QEventLoop(app)
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

where my `get_data(stock)`, **which we can think of as an basic aiohttp json call**, is defined as

```
async def get_data(stock_ticker):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('https://www.finra.org/finra-data/browse-catalog/equity-short-interest/data') as response:
            cfruid = session.cookie_jar.filter_cookies('https://www.finra.org/')["__cfruid"].value
            print("CFRUID", cfruid)
            five_months_date = date.today() + relativedelta(months=-5)

            headers = {
                'authority': 'services-dynarep.ddwa.finra.org',
                'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.6',
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'cookie': f'XSRF-TOKEN={cfruid};',
                'origin': 'https://www.finra.org',
                'referer': 'https://www.finra.org/',
                'x-xsrf-token': cfruid,
            }

            json_data = {
                'fields': [
                    'settlementDate',
                    'issueName',
                    'symbolCode',
                    'marketClassCode',
                    'currentShortPositionQuantity',
                    'previousShortPositionQuantity',
                    'changePreviousNumber',
                    'changePercent',
                    'averageDailyVolumeQuantity',
                    'daysToCoverQuantity',
                    'revisionFlag',
                ],
                'dateRangeFilters': [],
                'domainFilters': [],
                'compareFilters': [
                    {
                        'fieldName': 'symbolCode',
                        'fieldValue': 'GME',
                        'compareType': 'EQUAL',
                    },
                    {
                        'fieldName': 'settlementDate',
                        'fieldValue': str(five_months_date),
                        'compareType': 'GREATER',
                    },
                ],
                'multiFieldMatchFilters': [],
                'orFilters': [],
                'aggregationFilter': None,
                'sortFields': [
                    '-settlementDate',
                    '+issueName',
                ],
                'limit': 50,
                'offset': 0,
                'delimiter': None,
                'quoteValues': False,
            }

            async with session.post('https://services-dynarep.ddwa.finra.org/public/reporting/v2/data/group/OTCMarket/name/ConsolidatedShortInterest',
                              headers=headers, json=json_data) as response2:
                short_interest_data = await response2.json()
                return short_interest_data
```

I was able to have the coroutine work and return data in its own file by creating a task and awaiting it. I also tried using the `loop` instead. What am I missing? Note, other regular methods work when the button is clicked so I know it is just asyncio that refuses to run.

Edit: It seems to hang at the beginning of the `aiohttp` part not running the print statement I have within `get_data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using QThread seems to help with this

```py
class DataWorker(QThread):
    data_ready = Signal(dict)

    def __init__(self, stock_ticker):
        super().__init__()
        self.stock_ticker = stock_ticker

    async def get_data(self):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            # ... Your existing async code to fetch data ...
        self.data_ready.emit(short_interest_data)

    def run(self):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.run_until_complete(self.get_data())
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    # your existing code
    def update_data(self):
        stock_ticker = self.search_bar.text()
        print("Entered tickers: ", stock_ticker)

        self.data_worker = DataWorker(stock_ticker)
        self.data_worker.data_ready.connect(self.setup_data)
        self.data_worker.start()
# other codes
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I can't verify whether this is completely correct, because your code does not look **complete**, but it seems that after this correction, you can use async functions.